# How should I respond to questions asked before being allowed to enter the United States?

Tags: visas, air-travel, customs-and-immigration

I want to travel to Florida for 3 days, just for a party. If CBP officers ask me the purpose of my visit, and how long I plan to stay, is it safe to tell them the truth, that I am traveling for an event, it's a 3-day stay, from Friday to Monday?

Reason why I asked because I spent 4 months in the us and will be returning after 5 months in my own country .

I just wanna know if I should say traveling for a party or traveling for an event.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71433/discussion-on-question-by-britany-watson-how-should-i-respond-to-questions-asked).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say "party" or "celebration;" you don't need to add anything else unless they ask.

If they do, explain it simply (eg. "my cousin's wedding for 3 days"). *Do not lie to an immigration officer, on a visa application, or anywhere else*, or you might not be able to re-enter the US. It's not worth it, especially with the current administration.

Answer (score 23):

To your comment that you want to know if you should mention your reason for travel a party or an event:

There is no harm in saying it's a party at a friend's place along with the address. The officer may or may not ask the details of a party which would go on for 3 days, that really depends on him. **EDIT: This goes for a beach party too**

People always travel for birthdays, bridal showers, etc. So using the word party is ok as long as you know where you would be staying for the 3 days and what the party is about.

The word event usually refers to things like a conference where you have an invitation letter and qualifications to attend it; or something similar. However, if it is an event like a concert, festival etc then can say that you're going to ABC event at XYZ place.

Just be truthful and explain it as you feel easy.

Comment: if you edit the question to explain what the party is about you may get a more suited answer

Comment: @BritanyWatson Lying to an immigration officer, specially in the US can result in deportation and prohibition of entry to the country. Be certain, you should never lie or "paint the truth" to an immigration officer. Especially when you got nothing to hide, a party is not illegal nor a reason to deny you entry.

Comment: @BritanyWatson you're not asking any more questions that we can answer or help you with. Simply saying 'I'm not sure' is not going to do anything for you. Ask us something, give us details, or be happy with the answer already given.

Comment: Event is a very generic term, there's nothing wrong with using it to describe an informal social event such as a party.

Comment: Whatever term you pick for a quick answer, it should not seem to be deceptive if you are asked for more details and answer accurately.

Comment: These officials are looking for people trying to illegally work or immigrate to the US.  Visiting friends for a party is probably the least concerning thing you can say to them.  Be confident, tell the truth and don't overstay your visa and you should have no problems.  If you sound like you are trying to hide something, you could have issues.